# Symfony Doctrine exclude persisted entity

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have an entity `Key` (Not the real name, I know Key is forbidden) and I need, in a loop, get a `Key` with `state=1`, and change it to `state=2`. This is my script :

```
        /* Each object */
        for ($i=0; $i < $order->getQuantity(); $i++) {

            /* get available key */
            $key = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Key')->findOneBy(array('state' => 1));

                $key->setState(2); // On la rend active
                $this->_em()->persist($key);
            }
        }
```

My probleme is with this line : `$key = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Key')->findOneBy(array('state' => 1));`

Doctrine always get the same first key with `state=1`. If I flush directly in the loop it's ok, but I can have a very big loop and I don't want to flush XXXX times.

Is there a way to don't get already persisted entity ? How can I say to Doctrine to get a `Key with` `state=1` **ONLY** if I don't already persisted ?

Thanks !

Comment: Perhaps I am missing some context from your example, but why are you fetching records one-by-one in a loop, and not returning all with `->findBy(['state' => 1])`? Indeed, if you just want to update a bunch of records you could just create a DQL/SQL update query instead, optionally put it into a custom `KeyRepository`.

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you do this:

```
$keys = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Key')->findBy(array('state' => 1));
foreach($keys as $key) {
    $key->setState(2);
    $this->_em()->persist($key);
}
$this->_em()->flush();
```

Thereby each key will only be persisted once and because persisting things is symfony logic only you have only one DB write action during the flush-function where all persisted items will be stored

Answer (score 0):

In addition to retrieving and looping over your entities, you can also use DQL (unless I am missing context from your question that precludes this).

For example:

```
$dql    = 'UPDATE AppBundle:Key k SET k.state = 2 WHERE k.state = 1';
$query  = $this->_em->createQuery($dql);
$result = $query->getResult();
```

This is untested obviously. It's been a while since I wrote DQL so you might want to consult the docs. Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Persisting means "Hey Doctrine, let's be aware of that entity instance!".

It's used (as you surely already know) when you create a new entity instance (`$key = new Key();`), and then you want Doctrine to be aware of it (`$em->persist($key);`) to be able to add a new record in the database on flush (`$em->flush()`).

All entity instances retrieved with Doctrine are already persisted (Doctrine is already aware of them).

So, in your code, the `persist` call is useless. And as you don't flush, the database is not updated.
Then, in the next loop, when you request from the database (`->findOneBy(...)`), you will get again the same entity instance, with `state` still equals to 1.

Finally, to answer your questions "Is there a way to don't get already persisted entity ? How can I say to Doctrine to get a `Key with state=1` **ONLY** if I don't already persisted ?":

No, it's just impossible.